# Decode data received from onProgramAccountChange for orca pool

Tags: solana

I want to get streaming pool prices for orca on solana, that is the sqrtPrice (see here https://everlastingsong.github.io/account-microscope/#/whirlpool/whirlpool/FpCMFDFGYotvufJ7HrFHsWEiiQCGbkLCtwHiDnh7o28Q). I am using onProgramAccountChange:

```
const { Connection, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');

const poolAddress = 'FpCMFDFGYotvufJ7HrFHsWEiiQCGbkLCtwHiDnh7o28Q'; 
const orcaTokenProgramId = 'whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc'; 
const solanaConnection = new Connection(HTTP_ENDPOINT,{wsEndpoint:WSS_ENDPOINT});
     
 (async()=>{
            const subscriptionId = await solanaConnection.onProgramAccountChange(
                new PublicKey(orcaTokenProgramId),
                      (A) => {
                           console.log(A.accountInfo.data)
                      },   
                'processed' 
            );
        })()
```

I receive updates, but now I am stuck - how do I decode the data ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the SDK provided by orca: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@orca-so/whirlpools-sdk

```
yarn add @orca-so/whirlpools-sdk
yarn add @coral-xyz/anchor
yarn add decimal.js
```

You can parse a pool account using the following code:

```
const accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey("B6LL9aCWVuo1tTcJoYvCTDqYrq1vjMfci8uHxsm4UxTR"));
const pool: WhirlpoolData = WHIRLPOOL_CODER.decode(AccountName.Whirlpool, accountInfo.data);
console.log(pool);
```

Note that in the code you provided you will have to check the account discriminator to ensure you are not deserializing another account type.

Comment: Nice! How can I filter for a specific pool (given by poolAddress)?